# How can I push the variable value to the stack?

Tags: assembly, stack, mips, qtspim

In my Mips program, I need to store the value of a variable in the stack but when I try to save it to the place that stack pointer points I got a syntax error(at the last line shown below) in QtSpim. To me it is true that we can **sw** a floating point register to the stack position. I really do not understand the reason of this error and will appreciate any help.

```
li.s $f12,4.0
s.s $f12,A
addi $sp,$sp,-4
sw $ra,0($sp)
addi $sp,$sp,-4
l.s $f18,A
sw $f18,0($sp) #causes syntax error !
```

Comment: Think about the machine encoding for `sw`: it only has a 5-bit field to indicate which integer register to store.  The opcode that stores FP registers has a different mnemonic.  (And BTW, you don't need two separate `addi` instructions.  Just modify `sp` once, and use stores with offsets of `0(sp)` and `4(sp)`.)  Also, if you'd used an integer register to copy 4 bytes from `A` to the stack, you could have used `sw`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using lwc1 and swc1 instead of lw and sw for floating points works.

```
li.s $f12,4.0
s.s $f12,A
addi $sp,$sp,-4
sw $ra,0($sp)
addi $sp,$sp,-4
l.s $f18,A
swc1 $f18,0($sp)
```